# Issue on detect, formatting and initialize external hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

I have this external hard disk (a WD Elements 25A2) that can't be found on this PC but it's shown in control panel which says that it works fine (spoiler: not true). Anyway i'm trying to initialize and format it with no success.

In Windows default disk management it results not allocated so trying to solve that gives back a cyclic redundancy check error. What can I do instead of getting a hammer?

Tell me if you need any more info.

DW Dashbord screenshot:
[image: DW Dashbord screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide disk's model?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: In diskmgmt.msc, if all is unallocated, i.e., free space, create a partition and format it, presumably NTFS for Windows.

Comment: i've tried but it gives back 'cyclic redundancy check error'

Comment: 'cyclic redundancy check error' means a bad sector - go and get the hammer.

Comment: Have you tried WD's [Western Digital Dashboard](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en&p=279) tool to check the drive? (Also, the unit might have a USB-toSATA drive adapter PCB inside, which might be useful with a different HDD, so check that before using the hammer.)

Comment: The only thing that seems unusual it the voic that says Drive healt = Poor = A S.M.A.R.T. attribute has exceeded its threshold i've edited the question with a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have told us your drive is dead or dying.

If it contains valuable data you should pursue data recovery options.

Answer (score 1):

The drive has failed.

These models of drives have onboard USB interfaces, which means there's no SATA-to-USB adapter that you could bypass or replace. You won't be able to make any use of this drive.

Data recovery may be possible, but as always with data recovery you either have to have deep pockets or nothing to loose. The latter approach includes data carving using usual data recovery software (relationship vely easy) or even soldering a SATA cable directly to the board (difficult, requires soldering hardware and some understanding of electronics).